# How to find WFS layer geometry type, when the layer is empty (0 features)?

Tags: geometry, wfs, ogr

Is it possible to find the geometry type of a layer in a WFS, using OGR, when the layer is empty (0 features)?

Comment: Are you using an OGR (GDAL) command line utility (which one?), or C/C++ API, or Python?  Give us some more information about how you're using GDAL (OGR).  Does `GetGeomType()` (or `OGR_L_GetGeomType()`) work on WFS layers ( https://gdal.org/api/ogrlayer_cpp.html#classOGRLayer_1a818a25520ce08d5a681443348e930604 )?

Comment: I just tried `ogrinfo "WFS:https://ahocevar.com/geoserver/wfs?service=WFS" WFSLayerMetadata` and it reported:  `Geometry: None` even when it DOES have features.  So that didn't help.

Comment: There are also servers that have `"gml:GeometryPropertyType"` in DescribeFeatureType and then it is not possible to know the exact geometry type without reading the data. In that case GDAL usually prints the geometry type as `Unknown (any)`, not `None`.

Answer (score 1):

I just tried:

```
ogrinfo -al -so http://localhost:8080/geoserver/ows?service=wfs&version=1.1.0&request=getfeature&typename=ian:states
```

and amongst other things it says that my geometry type is a `Multi Surface`.

```
using driver `WFS' successful.
Metadata:
  ABSTRACT=This is the reference implementation of WFS 1.0.0 and WFS 1.1.0, supports all WFS operations including Transaction.
  PROVIDER_NAME=The ancient geographes INC
  TITLE=GeoServer Web Feature Service

Layer name: ian:states
Metadata:
  KEYWORD_1=features
  KEYWORD_2=states
  TITLE=states
Geometry: Multi Surface
Feature Count: 55
Extent: (-179.149000, -14.549000) - (179.778000, 71.365000)
Layer SRS WKT:
GEOGCRS["NAD83",
    DATUM["North American Datum 1983",
        ELLIPSOID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.257222101,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
        ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    CS[ellipsoidal,2],
        AXIS["geodetic latitude (Lat)",north,
            ORDER[1],
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
        AXIS["geodetic longitude (Lon)",east,
            ORDER[2],
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    USAGE[
        SCOPE["unknown"],
        AREA["North America - NAD83"],
        BBOX[14.92,167.65,86.46,-47.74]],
    ID["EPSG",4269]]
Data axis to CRS axis mapping: 2,1
Geometry Column = geom_4269
gml_id: String (0.0) NOT NULL
pop_2018: Integer64 (0.0)
area: Real (0.0)
```

If you don't have to use OGR then it is as easy to just make a `DescribeFeatureType` request directly to the WFS Server.

```
curl "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/ows?service=wfs&version=1.1.0&request=describeFeatureType&typename=ian:states"
```

which returns:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:ian="http://ianturton.com/ian" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://ianturton.com/ian">
  <xsd:import namespace="http://www.opengis.net/gml" schemaLocation="http://localhost:8080/geoserver/schemas/gml/3.1.1/base/gml.xsd"/>
  <xsd:complexType name="statesType">
    <xsd:complexContent>
      <xsd:extension base="gml:AbstractFeatureType">
        <xsd:sequence>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="pop_2018" nillable="true" type="xsd:long"/>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="area" nillable="true" type="xsd:double"/>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="geom_4269" nillable="true" type="gml:MultiSurfacePropertyType"/>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="geom_2163" nillable="true" type="gml:MultiSurfacePropertyType"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
      </xsd:extension>
    </xsd:complexContent>
  </xsd:complexType>
  <xsd:element name="states" substitutionGroup="gml:_Feature" type="ian:statesType"/>
</xsd:schema>
```